# Tableau Calculated fields with data blending

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have 2 different data sources DS1 and DS2

DS1 has week #( 1 to 49) , corresponding sales , ID

DS 2 has week #(50 to 52) , corresponding sales , ID

I did a data blending using ID as the relationship.

Question :

1. How do I draw a graph between week # and sales for the complete data (week 1 till week 52)
2. Does calculated field provide functions to get this done ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should provide more information about your data and your code, so we can get a clue what could result in your problem

Comment: @kabaehr ..I just wanted to know how to get this done ? using calculated field or any other option tableau provides.

Comment: Data blending is the wrong solution for this task. You want to form a union. Unions are  supported in version 9.3+

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Thank you.I have a huge data set and running the query takes an hour or so each time . Do we have anyother alternative other than unions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to enter this as a proposed solution rather than a comment. A union in the tableau data source screen is 100% the best way to go. If the 2 datasources have the same columns, you shouldn't need to re-pull the data. All of the work is done in Tableau.

Drag the "new union" pill into your data source pane and select the tables that you want to bring together, in this case DS 1 and DS 2.

The one caveat is that you have to be in v9.3+ like @AlexBlakemore said.

Comment: @ Stephen berndt -- Thank you ! But I see the union works if the tables are within the same Excel file in the form of tabs ; but in my case I have two different excel files and how do I union them ?